# Gatsby - Custom activeClass for list items

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I am building my first project with gatsby and was wondering if the following is posisble:

Would it be possible to create a custom function that acts kind of like `activeClassName`?

What I want to achieve:

I have a simple list

```
<ul>
    <li activeItemClassName="active">Item 1</li>
    <li activeItemClassName="active">Item 2</li>
    <li activeItemClassName="active">Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Now I would like to have some kind of config file, maybe a json, where i can set `item1: 0/1` for example and depending on that value, the `activeItemClassName="active"` gets applied a specific css class.

Is that possible somehow?

Comment: The config part doesn't really make sense to me. Are you using some kind of CSS lib like styled-components? I guess any styling trick you want to do is easy with styled-components

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a broad question without knowing your data structure even your format files. The following workaround can be adapted to any kind of data (JSON, markdown, etc).

Let's say you have one markdown file for each item such:

```
---
name: Item 1
key: items
active: true
---
## Your Item 1 body
```

*Note: you can adapt the structure to a JSON format file, the idea is exactly the same.*

Before querying those files, you should set properly your filesystem, something like:

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
  options: {
    name: `items`,
    path: `${__dirname}/src/data/items`,
  },
},
```

Keep in mind that in this sample, you will have one file per item. In this case, they will be stored under `/src/data/items` (`/src/data/items/item1.md`, etc). Once Gatsby recognizes your files, will be able to put them into the filesystem and you will be able to query those files via GraphQL in your page using a [page query](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/page-query/). In your page:

```
const yourPage = ({ data }) => {
   const { allMarkdownRemark } = data;

  return <Layout>
     <ul>
     {allMarkdownRemark.edges.map(({ node: item }) => {
      let { name, active } = item.frontmatter;
      
      return <li className={active ? "myClass" : "myOtherClass"} key={name}>{name}</li>
    });
    }
    </ul>
  </Layout>;
};

export const yourPageData = graphql`
    query getYourPageData{
        allMarkdownRemark(filter: { frontmatter: { key: { eq: "items" }}}) {
            edges {
                node {
                    html
                    frontmatter {
                        name
                        active 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
`;
```

Note: your query may differ if you use another kind of data file, take a look at your GraphQL *playground (`localhost:8000/___graphql`) to adapt the query. It's really useful the `key` field to improve the performance of the query and avoid retrieving all the markdown data in this case.*

There's a lot of information in the snippet above, however, it's kinda self-explanatory. At this point, you only need to query your data (`allMarkdownRemark`), filtering by the `key` field. Your data will be stored under `props.data`, so you can destructurate it. The next step is to loop through this data (items) and get your `active` value to set your class. Don't forget the `key` of the looped element. You only remain to add your CSS styles to that class.

You can adapt the markdown approach to any kind of data, JSON is perfectly valid too and the idea is exactly the same, it will only change the GraphQL query.